# list.onItenClickListner is not being called

Tags: android

I don't know why but when I am clicking on a list row nothing is happening ie the control is not going in `list_places.setOnItemClickListener`

```
    final ListView list_places=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_places);
    final ListView list_county=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_county);


    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    //get MapController that helps to set/get location, zoom etc.
    mMapController = mapView.getController();

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0L, 50.0f, this);

    final List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mapmarker);
    itemizedoverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable,mapView);

    mCurrentLatitude=(double) +28.63144713;
    mCurrentLongitude=(double) +77.38672751;
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(mCurrentLatitude*1000000),(int)(mCurrentLongitude*1000000));
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point,null, "Du er her");
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mMapController.animateTo(point);
    mMapController.setCenter(point);

    mButtonCounty=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bttn_county);
    mButtonRadar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bttn_radar);
    mContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mContainerView=(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container_view);

    final Thread dataThread=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run()
        {
            getFiveNearShops();

            DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext);
            myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext);

            try
            {
                myDbHelper.createDataBase();
            } 
            catch (IOException ioe) 
            {
                throw new Error("Unable to create database");
            }

            try 
            {
                myDbHelper.openDataBase();
                mCountyAndShops = myDbHelper.getCountyList();
            }
            catch(SQLException sqle)
            {

                throw sqle;

            }
            finally
            {
                myDbHelper.close();
            }
        }
    });
    dataThread.start();

    Thread displayThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

         try
         {
             dataThread.join();
         }
         catch (InterruptedException e) 
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }  
         mHandler.post(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() 
            {
                list_places.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
                list_places.setDivider(null);
                mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

                list_county.setAdapter(new CountyListEfficientAdapter(getApplicationContext(),mCountyAndShops));
                list_county.setDivider(null);
            }
        });

        }
    });
    displayThread.start();

    list_county.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent("com.similarlayers.finnpolet.ShopList");
            intent.putExtra("countyId",mCountyAndShops.get(position)[2]);
            intent.putExtra("countyName",mCountyAndShops.get(position)[0]);
            Log.v("click","click");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    list_places.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.v("clickplaces","clickplaces");

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your list_places in not in ui thread through you use mHandler.post,put your list_places  in your UI thread , i think you should use AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

I think u may import Some other Library....

Import Below .............

```
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
```

and this is my code for select item from List...

```
    ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long position) {
              Log.d("Current Position u Click", " " + position);

        }
    });
```

Try this ...... May be u get Help....

Comment: i am not getting any error the thing is when i am clicking in ListView  the control is not going into   ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long position) {
              Log.d("Current Position u Click", " " + position);

        }
    });   though once it went into it i am doing all things right i dun kno whats wrong

Comment: i think so it's cant call because of Thared.....
Not sure about this but ....
1st get all data in any Array than u call that data in listview with Adapter....
May b it can be work.... Theard some time not call activity so that...